# Pass number of images as parameter to NextGen Gallery

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

Hi is there a way to pass through a parameter indicating the number of images (thumbnails) displayed on a page? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use the Next Gen Smooth Gallery plug in which is a small additional plugin which makes customizing slideshows and galleries from the nextgen plug in VERY easy.